# First element of array by condition

Tags: php, array-filter

I am looking for an elegant way to get the first (and only the first) element of an array that satisfies a given condition.

**Simple example:**

Input:

```
[
    ['value' => 100, 'tag' => 'a'],
    ['value' => 200, 'tag' => 'b'],
    ['value' => 300, 'tag' => 'a'], 
 ]
```

Condition: `$element['value'] > 199`

Expected output:

```
['value' => 200, 'tag' => 'b']
```

I came up with several solutions myself:

1. Iterate over the array, check for the condition and break when found
2. Use array_filter to apply condition and take first value of filtered:

   ```
   array_values(
       array_filter(
           $input, 
           function($e){
               return $e['value'] >= 200;
           }
       )
   )[0];
   ```

Both seems a little cumbersome. Does anyone have a cleaner solution? Am i missing a built-in php function?

Comment: Can you explain your it more?

Comment: "Iterate over the array, check for the condition and break when found" is the __cleanest and fastest__ solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's **no need** to use all above mentioned functions like `array_filter`. Because `array_filter` **filters** array. And **filtering** is not the same as **find first value**. So, just do this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (meetsCondition($value)) {
        $result = $value;
        break;
        // or: return $value; if in function
    }
}
```

`array_filter` will filter **whole** array. So if your required value is first, and array has 100 or more elements, `array_filter` will still check all these elements. So, do you really need 100 iterations instead of 1? The answer is clear - **no**.

Comment: This is the best answer on the page because a conditional break avoids doing needless cycles.  `array_filter()` is not able to short circuit and is therefore doomed to iterate the entire array.

Answer (score 32):

The shortest I could find is using `current`:

```
current(array_filter($input, function($e) {...}));
```

[`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) essentially gets the first element, or returns `false` if its empty.

If the code is being repeated often, it is probably best to extract it to its own function.

Comment: Thanks! Using `current` is definitely nicer and faster than doing the `array_values` thing

Comment: Be conscient that it is not optimized : array_filter will execute your function on every element of the array, which includes all successors of the "winner". It may be important (if your array has thousands of values) or not (if it has only 3).

Comment: this solution is ok for small number of items, but for big arrays, it's horrendously slow...

Answer (score -2):

Your array :

```
$array = [
['value' => 100, 'tag' => 'a'],
['value' => 200, 'tag' => 'b'],
['value' => 300, 'tag' => 'a'], 
];
```

To find the entries via conditions, you could do this

```
$newArray = array_values(array_filter($array, function($n){ return $n['value'] >= 101 && $n['value'] <= 400; }));
```

With this you can set to values, min and max numbers.

if you only want to set a min number, you can omit the max like this

```
$arrayByOnlyMin = array_values(array_filter($array, function($n){ return $n['value'] >= 199; }));
```

This would return :

```
 array(2) {
 [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(200)
      ["tag"]=>
      string(1) "b"
    }
 [1]=>
   array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(300)
      ["tag"]=>
      string(1) "a"
    }
}
```

so calling `$arrayByOnlyMin[0]` would give you the first entry, that matches your min condition.

Comment: aaand, I just noticed, that this is basically the exact same thing that you did :-D - so basically.. You are doing it right

Comment: This method is indeed technically right if we only look at the inputs and outputs. However, this is absolutely not efficient. The use of `array_filter` here is not the best option. `array_filter` will walk the complete input array before returning it's output, and this is not what we want. We just want to return the first item which match the predicate.
You could use a `filter` only if PHP was having lazy execution, but it's not the case. If you're looking for a lazy filter operation, you could have a look at a library I built here: https://github.com/loophp/collection/